# SQL - Cast two alias in BigDecimal

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS lastmonth,
   SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
          AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS lastmonth2
FROM incident_view
WHERE customer_company_name = "Company"
```

Hello everyone,

how Can I cast the two results (lastmonth and lastmonth2, which are both Int) into the Bigdecimal type/double, or any other decimal type?

Would appreciate some help.

Cheers

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned `BigDecimal`, which is a Java type, not a MySQL type.  In any case, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) recommends using either a number of types, including the `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` MySQL type, to convert with Java's `BigDecimal`, so your cast might look something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
         AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS NUMERIC) AS lastmonth,
       CAST(SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
         AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS NUMERIC) AS lastmonth2
FROM incident_view
WHERE customer_company_name = "Company"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST( .. AS DECIMAL)`

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS DECIMAL) AS lastmonth,
    CAST(SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
          AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS DECIMAL) AS lastmonth2
FROM incident_view
WHERE customer_company_name = "Company"
```